# How to Get date between two date and time using MS SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table with columns 
Like

```
----------------------------------------------------
DateFrom   | Dateto     | TimeFrom | TimeTo| ZoneID |
----------------------------------------------------+
2014-09-01 | 2014-09-30 | 03:00    | 08:00 |   1    |
----------------------------------------------------+
2014-09-01 | 2014-09-30 | 09:00    | 15:00 |   1    |  
----------------------------------------------------+
2014-09-01 | 2014-09-30 | 16:00    | 23:00 |   1    |
----------------------------------------------------+
2014-09-01 | 2015-09-30 | 03:00    | 08:00 |   2    |
```

There is i want to get record between datefrom and dateto ,timefrom and timeto
If i try to get with date 2014-10-03 then it's showing all records Please help how to get specific record using sql query.
Thanks in advanced.

i want to get records between todate and fromdate, timefrom and timeto both

This query i was write please check.

```
    SELECT       
    Tariff.TariffZoneID,CAST(TariffDate.TimeFrom AS VARCHAR(32)) AS TimeFrom ,CAST(TariffDate.TimeTo AS VARCHAR(32)) AS TimeTo,'2014-09-25 00:00:00.000' AS DateFrom,'2014-09-25 00:00:00.000' AS DateTo,TariffZone.Name,TariffZone.MaximumPrice,
    TariffZone.FactionMinute,Tariff.SequenceNo,tariffdate.weekId,   Tariff.Time,Tariff.IsFaction,Tariff.Amount
FROM 
    TariffDate 
    INNER JOIN TariffZone ON TariffDate.TariffZoneID = TariffZone.TariffZoneID 
    INNER JOIN Tariff ON TariffZone.TariffZoneID = Tariff.TariffZoneID 
    WHERE TariffDate.TariffDateID >= (
            SELECT ISNULL(MAX(tariffdateid), 0) 
            FROM TariffDate 
            where datefrom <= cast('2014-09-25 00:00:00.000' as date) 
            and timeFrom<=cast('05:00:00.0000000' as time) and FacilityID =2 and WeekID= datepart(dw,CAST('2014-09-25 00:00:00.000' AS DATE)) 
            )
    AND
    TariffDate.TariffDateID <= 
    (
        SELECT ISNULL(MIN(tariffdateid) , 0)
        FROM TariffDate 
        WHERE dateto <= CAST('2014-09-25 00:00:00.000' AS DATE) 
        and  timeTo <=CAST('07:00:00.0000000' AS TIME) 
        and FacilityID =2 and WeekID= datepart(dw,CAST('2014-09-25 00:00:00.000' AS DATE))) 
    and Tariff.FacilityID =2
```

Comment: And what results do you actually want?  Please update the question with this information.

Comment: I want to get records between todate and fromdate, totime and fromtime

Comment: That is not clear... please show the expected result set.

Comment: On first glimpse: Your table holds dates and times separately. This suggests that we are not talking about time spans of, say, 2014-09-01 03:00 to 2014-09-30 08:00, but of 2014-09-01 to 2014-09-30 daily from 03:00 to 08:00. (Otherwise the dba would have chosen datetimes instead.)

Answer (score 0):

You should combine `DateFrom` and `TimeFrom` column values and work with `datetime` sql type.
Modify your SQL conditions like this:

```
  WHERE (CAST(CAST(DateFrom AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(TimeFrom  AS TIME)) <= '2014-09-25 05:00:00'
        AND FacityID=....

  WHERE (CAST(CAST(DateTo AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(TimeTo  AS TIME)) <= '2014-09-25 07:00:00'
        AND FacityID=....
```

You are not getting all records, because for every date that match the condition you get only records that match the separate time condition (<7:00 etc).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM test WHERE CONCAT(datefrom,' ',timefrom) <= '2014-08-07 10:00'

you can make it simple by using CONCAT

Answer (score 0):

I hope, if you use the below code structure as filter for your query, it will get the records for fromdate to todate.

```
WHERE (CAST('2014-09-25 00:00:00.000' AS DATE)!>dateto and CAST('2014-09-25 00:00:00.000' AS time) !>timeTo)...
and (CAST('2014-09-25 00:00:00.000' AS DATE)!<datefrom and CAST('2014-09-25 00:00:00.000' AS time) !<timeFrom)...
```